# how to debug Window service in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, window

I have create window service that read data from database.But, It does not read data from database.I am trying to debug but could not happen. I have written several log using eventviewer.but Log are not written in eventviewer.However, all the code work in Window form applications, the code is

```
eventLog1.WriteEntry("GApps Sync is Collecting parameters from GUI seting", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
       var folderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
         Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "GAppsSync");
       if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
       {
           eventLog1.WriteEntry("Please stop service and Run GUI Tool set all the syn parameter", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);          
       }
        path = Path.Combine(folderPath, "databaseFile.db3");
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
        if (fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("GApps Sync is getting parameters from GUI tool", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
            try
            {
                using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("data source=" + path))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SQLiteCommand cmdSyncPara = new SQLiteCommand("Select SyncInterval, CRMSetting,GoogleSetting,SyncOption From Synchroniszation",con);
                    SQLiteDataReader dataReader = cmdSyncPara.ExecuteReader();
                    eventLog1.WriteEntry("GApps Sync is Reading database parameter:", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        SyncInterval = dataReader.GetString(0);
                        eventLog1.WriteEntry("GApps Sync is getting parameters from GUI tool Syncinterval:" + SyncInterval, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
                        CRMSetting = dataReader.GetString(1);
                        eventLog1.WriteEntry("GApps Sync is getting parameters from GUI tool CRMSetting:" + CRMSetting, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);

                        GoogleSetting = dataReader.GetString(2);
                        SyncOption = dataReader.GetString(3);
                    }
                    eventLog1.WriteEntry("GApps Sync got GUI sync Options and Sync Interval parameters", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information); 
                    SQLiteCommand cmdReadData = new SQLiteCommand("Select Enable, GmailId,GmailPassword,EmployeeAccount From SyncDataDetail",con);
                    SQLiteDataReader dataReaderDetail = cmdReadData.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dataReaderDetail.Read())
                    {
                        DataContainer dc = new DataContainer();
                        dc.Enable = bool.Parse(dataReaderDetail.GetString(0));
                        dc.EmailText = dataReaderDetail.GetString(1);
                        dc.Password = Decrypt(dataReaderDetail.GetString(2));
                        dc.EmployeeAccount = dataReaderDetail.GetString(3);
                        ItemCollection.Add(dc);
                    }
                    eventLog1.WriteEntry("GApps Sync got GUI Save Account Mapping ", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information); 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry("GApps Sync Failed to get GUI Save Account Mapping ", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error); 
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: How we are supposed to help you with such a general description? It is like 'my car do not run although it has all wheels and I am turning on the engine'...

Comment: I added code. It does not write some logs

Answer (score 1):

You should attach the process to the debugger in visual studio.
You can do this from the debug menu. Then clicking on attach to process.
A new window displays, select the process there and click on attach.
Now you are in debug mode for your windows service.

Source: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

the best way to debug the windows services edit your program.cs file like this

```
static class Program { 
    static void Main()  { 

        #if DEBUG ServiceName myService = new ServiceName();
            myService.onDebug(); 
        #else ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;

            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            {  
                new ServiceName() 
            }; 

            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun); 

        #endif
    } 
}
```

then run the file in debug mode add the break point where you want that. :)

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN ([Debug Windows Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.110).aspx))

Add a method to your service that runs the OnStart and OnStop methods:

```
internal void TestStartupAndStop(string[] args)
{
    this.OnStart(args);
    Console.ReadLine();
    this.OnStop();
}
```

Rewrite the Main method as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                MyNewService service1 = new MyNewService(args);
                service1.TestStartupAndStop(args);
            }
            else
            {
                // Put the body of your old Main method here.
            }
       }
```

Note: You also need another constructor for your service i.e.:

```
public Service1(string[] args)
```

if you want to pass arguments.

**In the Application tab of the project's properties, set the Output type to Console Application.** (do not forget this step!)

Choose Start Debugging (F5).

This will pop up a console window, run onStart, and patiently wait for you to hit a key in the console window to end your service.

To run the program as a Windows Service again, install it and start it as usual for a Windows Service. It's not necessary to reverse these changes.